# C++ Speed and Logical Flow

Tags: c++, performance, if-statement, optimization

I was wondering if there are any speed advantage to doing case B vs case A (or vice versa) in the following:

```
bool test1(){
// Check something, return true/false
}
bool test2(){
// Check something, return true/false
}
```

**Case A**

```
if(test1() && test2()){
    //execute XYZ
}
```

**Case B**

```
if(test1()){
  if(test2()){
      //execute XYZ
  }
}
```

I mean, if the routines involved in `test1()` and `test2()` take some time to execute, then intuitively some people may think that Case B may run faster, since `test2()` would only get executed if test 1 is true, or is the compiler smart enough to determine, within the logical sequence of Case A, that as soon as `test1(...)` fails, then `test2(...)` need not be checked?

Perhaps the above are equivalent, can someone let me know...

Answer (score 10):

`is the compiler smart enough to determine` yes it is, this is called [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), and works with `&&`, `||` and `?` operators (unless you overload them), as described in the standard in paragraphs 5.14, 5.15 and 5.16.

Comment: Thanks, so if you know that `test2()` will return false more often that `test1()`, is it more advantageous to write `test2() && test1()` over `test1() && test2()`?

Comment: Equally, if test2 takes much longer to execute you may want to run test1 first.

Comment: A comment I've made elsewhere: A more complete answer needs to include the statement "... if `operator&&` has not been overloaded.   If it has, then the boolean operator is treated more as a normal function, and both expressions will be evaluated.".

Comment: @Andre, fair enough, I added that.

Comment: I would like to emphasize that this is not something the optimizer does - it is guaranteed by the language that `test2` will only be executed if `test1` returns `true` (minus overloading), and it will happen in an unoptimized build just the same. While your references cover this aspect, you could state this more directly given that the asker seems to be unaware of it.

Answer (score 4):

They are equivalent, if `test1` returns false, `test2` will not be executed in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, test 2 will not get executed if test 1 is false.  They are identical in that regards.

Case A is preferred over Case B for readability.  You can see in one line both must be true, and by the ordering can see that test 1 is checked first.

Answer (score 1):

In java for example, he can avoid some tests if the answer already on hands. I don't have much time to test this case now. But you can test easily, make a very slow rotine on test2() and give a antecipate answer on test1(). Then if a quickly answer returned. C++ works like Java.

In your sample, only you has antecipate answer if returns of test1() is false. In other way test2() is required.

If you can wait, i will test tonight this case.

Answer (score -3):

`Case A` run faster, these are two reasons proved it.

1.It will [short-circuit evaluate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) for `&&`, `||` logical operators, etc. so `Case A` may cost less time than `Case B`

2.`if` statement will translate to `jmp` assembly language, it cost more time to excute. so `Case B` will cost more time than `Case A`.

Comment: Are you sure any optimiser worthy of the name will produce different output for those two?